# Opening a file having 2D coordinate system in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, netcdf

I have a NetCDF file that has locations and events stored in 2D coordinates. For instance, the coordinates are stored like this lat(x,y), lon(x,y). Please refer to the latitude variable example image attached below for what i mean

How can I open such a file in ArcGIS Pro without interpolation or any other conversion?

When I open it up it displays nothing as ArcGIS Pro is unable to read the data due to file being in 2D coordinate system.
It gives the error:
"One or both dimensions have variable spacing in their coordinate values"
[image]

Comment: lat(x,y) and lon(x,y) don't make sense.  Can you post the CSV file for download?  If not, can you include a screen shot of the CSV header and the first row or two of data?

Comment: @GBG sorry its a netcdf file. i just mistyped it. it looks something like this https://cfconventions.org/Data/cf-conventions/cf-conventions-1.2/build/ch05s02.html

Comment: lat(x,y) and lon(x,y) make sense for use cases like projected coordinate systems.  Can you show us the netcdf header info, like `ncdump -h filename.nc` `gdalinfo filename.nc` or something?

Comment: @DaveX i have added a screenshot which shows information about the netcdf from the Panoply spoftware. It shows that each variable is a 2D variable and if you see the header, it has  x,y dimensions and lat and lon. This is what my problem is. Could you help me with this?

Comment: It doesn't look like your netcdf file has metadata enough to determine the projection.  Several examples in https://cfconventions.org/Data/cf-conventions/cf-conventions-1.2/build/ch05s06.html show details on how to map projected coordinates to lat-lon in CF, but your screenshot doesn't appear to show any vars/metadata for projected coordinates.   Lacking those, Jersey Andy's suggestion is good: several datasets on a random lat,lon points. Something like the NCO operators' `ncks -H filename.nc` would dump into time,lat,lon,value records that could be converted into x,y, Point Data CSV files.

Answer (score 1):

Get your data into a simple CSV format, then use the "XY Point Data" option on the "Add Data" menu.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/layer-properties/add-x-y-coordinate-data-as-a-layer.htm

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/xy-table-to-point.htm